# Clang-format doesn't join function to return type if type is ALL_CAPS

Tags: clang-format

I'm noticing a strange behavior where clang-format will join a function name with its return type when the type is lower case, but not when the return type is all upper case.

Is there a way to get around this?  Maybe this is being influenced by some other setting?
I've also tried `BasedOnStyle: Microsoft`).  I have tried clang-format v12, v13, v14 and all seem to behave the same.

Desired format:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
ColumnLimit: 120
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 10
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 100000000
...
```

Original File:

```c
mytype
SomeFunctionLongName(
    uint32_t param1, // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    uint32_t param2, // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssssssss
    uint32_t param3 // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
);

MYTYPE
SomeFunctionLongNam2(
    MYTYPE param1, // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    MYTYPE *param2, // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssssssss
    MYTYPE **param3 // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
);
```

Run:

```
clang-format --style=file --verbose sample3.c
```

Result:

```
mytype SomeFunctionLongName(uint32_t param1, // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
                            uint32_t param2, // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssssssss
                            uint32_t param3  // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
);

MYTYPE
SomeFunctionLongNam2(MYTYPE param1,  // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
                     MYTYPE *param2, // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssssssss
                     MYTYPE **param3 // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
);
```